# Zero coupon bond calculations

Tags: finance-mathematics

I am given the following forward rate dynamics $df(t,u)=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(\frac{\sigma^2}{2})dt-\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\sigma dW$ and want to calculate the dynamics of the ZCB $p$ via the computations below. The second equality is clearly Ito lemma but equality three and four throws me off completely, can someone see whats going on?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notations in the snapshot are pretty messy. I prefer to proceed as follows.

Let $X_t = -\int_t^T f(t, u)du$. 
Note that
\begin{align*}
f(t, u) - f(0, u) = \frac{\partial }{\partial u}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\sigma^2(s, u)}{2} ds - \int_0^t \sigma(s, u) d W_s \right).
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
r_t = f(t, t) = f(0, t) + \frac{\partial }{\partial u}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\sigma^2(s, u)}{2} ds - \int_0^t \sigma(s, u) d W_s \right)\Big|_{u=t}.
\end{align*}
Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
\int_t^T f(t, u)du  - \int_t^T f(0, u)du &= \left(\int_0^t \frac{\sigma^2(s, T)}{2} ds - \int_0^t \sigma(s, T) d W_s \right) \\
&\qquad -\left(\int_0^t \frac{\sigma^2(s, t)}{2} ds - \int_0^t \sigma(s, t) d W_s \right).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
X_t &= - \int_t^T f(0, u)du + \left(\int_0^t \frac{\sigma^2(s, t)}{2} ds - \int_0^t \sigma(s, t) d W_s \right) \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad - \left(\int_0^t \frac{\sigma^2(s, T)}{2} ds - \int_0^t \sigma(s, T) d W_s \right).
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
dX_t &= f(0, t) dt + \frac{\sigma^2(t, t)}{2} dt - \sigma(t, t) d W_t \\
&\qquad + \frac{\partial }{\partial u}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\sigma^2(s, u)}{2} ds - \int_0^t \sigma(s, u) d W_s \right)\Big|_{u=t} dt
-\frac{\sigma^2(t, T)}{2} dt + \sigma(t, T) d W_t\\
&= r_t dt -\frac{\sigma^2(t, T)}{2} dt + \sigma(t, T) d W_t.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
dP(t, T) &= d\big(e^{X_t} \big)\\
&=P(t, T)\Big(dX_t + \frac{1}{2} d\langle X, X\rangle_t \Big)\\
&=P(t, T)\big(r_t dt + \sigma(t, T) d W_t \big).
\end{align*}

Comment: I dont quite understand the first equality for $dX$ where does then $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$-term come from?

Comment: Look at the second term $\left(\int_0^t \frac{\sigma^2(s, t)}{2} ds - \int_0^t \sigma(s, t) d W_s \right)$ in $X_t$, there is one $t$ in the integral limit and another $t$ in the integrand. The differential $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$, and evaluated at $t$, is for the $t$ in the integrand.

Comment: right, thats kind of odd.., how do you interpret that, some kind of chain rule?

Comment: You need to check the calculus book. How do you calculate the differential $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(x, y) dy\right)$?